# Error navigating back to questions list

Tags: support, bug

I get a window alert whenever i visit a question and click a back arrow to go back to the questions list. Is this expected behavior or is something broken?

> Error: For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to
>   remove the frames.

Edit: I was facing this in chrome browser. Windows 7, for some reason this is only happening in the main site not the meta!
[image]

Comment: Cant replicate on Windows 11 Chrome and firefox, can you specify browser version and OS. Also if using work allocated laptop as some domain policies kinda cause this behavior.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I have been using work desktop but i never had this issue earlier!